# "CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down" error while trying to create new Solr collection

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I've just downloaded the latest Solr version from the official website (8.9.0) and tried to create a collection with

```
solr create -c portal
```

But the command fails with the error

```
Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
```

There is no other (more specific) error message. Just that `CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down`.

For info, I can start `solr` with `solr start` which returns

```
Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 81485 running on port 8983
```

But then a few seconds later I also get

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
```

with no other specific error message. I have not changed anything from the default values in any config file. This is how I start my `solr`:

```
solr start -c -s /path/to/server/solr -m 1g -z localhost:2181,server2:2181,server3:2181
```

where `server2` and `server3` are IP addresses of the other two machines where I also have `solr` and `zookeeper` installed.

What can I do?

Comment: The full log should contain the error from why Solr is not running - usually it's because the core can't be initialized because of missing configuration (i.e. the configuration references a resource that can't be found or is invalid).

Comment: @MatsLindh How can I view the full logs? What I've posted is all that can be found in the logs directory.

Comment: Check the logs from when Solr is starting up/before/after the error's you've included, you can also start Solr in the foreground with `-f` or check the logs in the admin interface itself (if available).; Solr should output quite a bit to the log when starting up.

Comment: As I said in my post above, the startup logs of Solr *also* only indicate the issue "CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down". There is literally no other information available.

Comment: If there is _nothing else in the logs_ except for that error message, I'd recommend starting Solr in the foreground with `-f` - it should at least give you "solr is starting up"-messages (with a Solr logo in ascii), which libraries are being loaded, etc.